# Postgres cannot find distance function for gist index

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have a query like so:

```sql
SELECT * FROM mytable
ORDER BY geo_coords <-> ST_MakePoint(<some_lon>, <some_lat>)
```

The `geo_coords` column on `mytable` is a `GEOGRAPHY` type and I have a `GIST` index, called `myindex`, on that column.

When I run this query on enough records for the query planner to use the index, I get the following error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: missing support function 8 for attribute 1 of index "myindex"
```

I believe this means that postgres can't find the [distance support function](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/c30f54ad732ca5c8762bb68bbe0f51de9137dd72/src/backend/access/gist/gistscan.c#L310), but I am not sure how this is possible.

The [GIST support function table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/xindex.html#XINDEX-GIST-SUPPORT-TABLE) shows that function #8 is the `distance` function

Why wouldn't postgres be able to find the distance function? I am not sure how to further debug this.

Postgres Version:

```
PostgreSQL 12.6 on aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 7.3.1 20180712 (Red Hat 7.3.1-6), 64-bit
```

Postgis Version:

```
POSTGIS="3.0.2 2fb2a18" [EXTENSION] PGSQL="120" GEOS="3.8.0-CAPI-1.13.1 " PROJ="Rel. 5.2.0, September 15th, 2018" GDAL="GDAL 2.4.4, released 2020/01/08" LIBXML="2.9.1" LIBJSON="0.13.1" LIBPROTOBUF="1.3.2" WAGYU="0.4.3 (Internal)" RASTER (raster procs from "3.0.0 r17983" need upgrade)
```

Comment: 3.0 had a few issues with indexes on geography. It might be worth updating PostGIS

Comment: hey @JGH, thanks for the suggestion.  Unfortunately, we don't have the ability to upgrade from 3.0 on our system.  I am hoping there is another way to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are running 3.0.2, it should not be [this bug](https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/4608) which was fixed with [this commit](https://github.com/postgis/postgis/pull/528) in version 3.0.1 (see the [release notes](https://git.osgeo.org/gitea/postgis/postgis/raw/tag/3.0.1/NEWS)).

This is a PostGIS bug, and you should [report it](https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/#BugTracking).

Once there is a fix, you will need to upgrade. There is no way to get rid of bugs without upgrading.